# Linear Operator Boundedness

Tags: analysis

a) Show that the linear operator $L_2: \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ defined by $L_2(\langle x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,\ldots\rangle) = \langle(1+1/2)x_1, (1+ 1/2 + 1/4)x_2, \ldots, 1+1/2+\cdots+(1/2^{(n-1)})x_n,\ldots\rangle$ is bounded.

b) Find $\|L_2\|_\mathrm{OP}$ (smallest $M$ such that $\|L_2v\| \leq M\|v\|)$

Comment: You forgot to give the definition for the operator.

Comment: Questions posted here should generally not be phrased in a style suitable for assigning homework.  It can arouse reasonable suspicions that you copied a question without understanding it, as opposed to having an actual question in your mind that you're communicating to us. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I agree with Michael Hardy.

Answer (score 0):

1.$$\|L_2 x\|=\sqrt{\left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{2^{2}}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2x_1^2+\ldots+\left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2x_n^2+\ldots}\le\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2+\ldots}=2\|x\|$$
Thus $L_2$ is bounded and $\|L_2\|_{OP}\le 2$

2.Take $a_n=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots)$ which takes $1$ at the $n$-th position. Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\|L_2 a_n\|}{\|a_n\|}=2.$$
Which means $\|L_2\|_{OP}=2$